# Granting the create view privilege in mysql using cpanel/phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, mysql-error-1044

I am using cpanel and I wanted to grant a user `create view` privileges. When I created the user and database in cpanel it did not have an option for that.
So I tried to do it in phpMyAdmin using :

`GRANT CREATE VIEW ON (dbname).* TO '(db username)'@'localhost';`

and I get the error:

`#1044 - Access denied for user '(host username)'@'localhost' to database '(dbname)'`

Comment: Sure you didn't properly rename the database of your view?  Been there, done that.  It gives the same error if you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell this isn't possible with some configurations.

Answer (score 0):

What version of cpanel are you using?  I mine, I go to MySQL databases.  All your tables are listed with users who have privileges on those tables and the users are links.  When you click on one of the links, it takes you to a list of privileges that are checkboxes.  Couldn't be simpler, all though I find it difficult to trust something that makes my privilege handling so simple!

Is it possible that you don't have the grants yourself to give grants?

Comment: I am using cpanel 11.  And I think I have the same thing, but I do not think by selecting all privileges it allows create view.  If you check I don't think it is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same problem and after many searches when i look through the cpanel thoroughly i discovered something. To work with database we need to grant our user full privileges. Cpanel named this job differently. They call it "Add User To Database". Add your user with the database you desire. Then it'll work. Probably we miss it or we don't know what to do with it. So that we face this problem.